# Choosing releases config for umbrella project

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have 3 umbrella projects:

- business logic;
- Rest API;
- Web.

I have the following config in root `mix.exs`:

```
releases: [
        web: [
          applications: [web_project: :permanent]
        ],
        api: [
          applications: [rest_api_project: :permanent]
        ]
      ]
```

The problem is that every time I run `mix release release_name` the runtime config is loaded from the root project, not from the projects specified.

I even tried to load other configs the following way:

```
for config <- "../apps/*/config/releases.exs" |> Path.expand(__DIR__) |> Path.wildcard() do
  import_config config
end
```

However it doesn't seem to work, it is using the compile-time config.

Comment: Would not tweaking [`Config.Reader`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Config.Reader.html) help?

Comment: I was thinking the same, however the problem is that reader config is loaded at runtime, meaning that it will search for configs inside of release folder and releases doesn't seem to copy any of the umbrella projects `releases.exs` to the release assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have chosen to take a different path, since overlays don't provide any flexibility to using `steps` :

```
web: [
          applications: [my_app: :permanent],
          config_providers: [
            {Config.Reader, {:system, "RELEASE_ROOT", "apps/my_app/config/releases.exs"}},
            {Config.Reader, {:system, "RELEASE_ROOT", "apps/another_app/config/releases.exs"}},
          ],
          steps: [:assemble, &copy_configs/1]
        ]
```

This way I can extract the `path` and `config_providers` and move them to the releases folder:

```
defp copy_configs(%{path: path, config_providers: config_providers} = release) do
    for {_module, {_context, _root, file_path}} <- config_providers do
      # Creating new path
      new_path = path <> Path.dirname(file_path)
      # Removing possible leftover files from previous builds
      File.rm_rf!(new_path)
      # Creating directory if it doesn't exist
      File.mkdir_p!(new_path)
      # Copying files to the directory with the same name
      File.cp!(Path.expand(file_path), new_path <> "/" <> Path.basename(file_path))
    end

    release
  end
```

Comment: I am positive you should mark this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

After finding a similar [issue](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/9742) opened, the proposed solution by José Valim is to use overlays. The only problem currently with overlays is that you can only point at a specific folder, opposite to the flexibility you have with [Disitllery Overlays](https://hexdocs.pm/distillery/Mix.Releases.Overlays.html).

The final solution is the following:

```
releases: [
        web: [
          applications: [my_app: :permanent],
          config_providers: [{Config.Reader, {:system, "RELEASE_ROOT", "/releases.exs"}}],
          overlays: "apps/my_app/config"
        ]
   ]
```